# Operands Types do not Match - Assembly Code

Tags: assembly

so i have just started coding in Assembly and i am trying to create a simple program which evaluates an expression with the inputted x, and y. However, when i compile my code using TASM on a 64 bit win8, i get 1 error that `Operands Types do not Match`. Im not sure what that means; from what i understand it means that the 2 values are of different types. But how would i fix it?

x, y, z are integers

```
; eval z := (3 - 2*x)*x - 2*y + 1;  
; z :=(3 - 2*x) 
    mov al, '2'
    mul x
    sub ax, '3'
    mov z, ax

; eval z := z * x - 2   
    sub x, '2'
    mul z 
    mov z, ax

; eval z := z* y + 1
    mov al, '1'
    add al, y  ; error occurs here
    mul z
    mov z, ax
```

I have modified my program and tried to make it a little more simple using the fact that `3x-2x^2 -2y +1 =(3 - 2*x)*x - 2*y + 1`. But im still having trouble with the x^2 part. Im not sure how to implement imul properly and as a result i think im getting the undesired results. How would i do x*x in order to simulate x^2 using imul? From what i know, the result is in ax and the multiplicand is in al. But how do i move x to al (x is an int and al is byte right)?

```
; eval z := 3x-2x^2 -2y +1 =(3 - 2*x)*x - 2*y + 1;  
    mov ax, x
    add ax, ax
    add ax, x
    mov cx, ax
    mov bx, x
    imul bx     ;x^2
    add ax, ax  ; where ax is the result of the imul 
    sub cx, bx
    mov ax, cx
    mov bx, y
    add bx, bx
    inc bx
    sub ax, bx
    mov z, ax
```

Comment: Since `al` is byte-sized then so must `x` and `y` be for those instructions to be correct.

Comment: i am required to make x, y, and z to be integers, so how would i modify the code to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
; eval z := (3 - 2*x)*x - 2*y + 1;  
; z :=(3 - 2*x) 
    mov aX, x
    ADD AX,AX     ;X*2 - much faster than MUL
    sub ax, 3     ;note 3 not '3' as '3' is the ASCII character '3' = 33hex
                  ;result is 2x-3, not 3-2x! (not fixed!!)
    mov z, ax

; eval z := z * x - 2   
:: ! No - the expression required is z := (3 - 2*x)*x - (2*y) + 1
    sub aX, x ;Need word-size
    mul z
    mov z, ax

; eval z := z* y + 1
    add y, 1 ; NOT ascii - decimal (what about INC?)
    mov aX, y ;need word-size
    mul z
    mov z, ax
```

This should fix your syntax errors - and provide a few pointers about other problems which I haven't fixed.

Note that the expression `(3 - 2*x)*x - 2*y + 1` is `(3 - 2*x)*x - (2*y) + 1` I'm not sure whether you could resolve this

```
(3 - 2*x)*x - (2*y) + 1 = 3x-2x^2 -2y +1
```

or whether you have to use the constants and process it mechanically.

Regardless, you need to be very careful of the `3-2x` expression. Pay very close attention to the `sign` of the result. Can `x` or `y` be negative? That might also change your thinking.

So - overall :

Be very sure of the expression you are required to evaluate

'4' is ASCII 4, not decimal 4

AX for word-size variables (16-bit) AL for byte-size.

Be careful of the potential for negative arguments or intermediate results

`ADD AX,AX` if far faster than `MUL` by 2

INC is shorter and faster than `ADD xx,1`

And are you really sure of `X` and `y` - might they not need to be `[x]` and `[y]`? (might depend on your assembler mode)

Comment: i didnt think about it before, but the result can be negative. So i should be using imul instead?

Comment: DX:AX - most-significant word to DX, least to AX.

Comment: im not sure what u mean.

Comment: i modified my code, see above, but im still having trouble with the imul.